# git: Is there a command line option for "Sort by date" for gitk?

Tags: linux, git, command-line, gitk

I'm trying to find a command line option for gitk that has the same effect of "Strictly sort by date" in the "View / Edit view..." window.

`man gitk` shows a very limited number of options compared to those available in the GUI.

Comment: CLI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576503/how-can-i-make-git-log-order-based-on-authors-timestamp

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [`man gitk`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitk) at least mentions it does take the same options than **[`git rev-list`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list)**, including

```
--date-order
```

> This option is similar to `--topo-order` in the sense that no parent comes before all of its children, but otherwise things are still ordered in the commit timestamp order.

See "[Guide to understanding gitk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570535/guide-to-understanding-gitk)" for more.

---

Note: if `-d` or `--date-order` is really the argument you are after, better not using too much, according to Linus himself (from [lists-archives.com/git](http://lists-archives.com/git/655429-visualizing-git-s-git-repo.html) or [www.spinics.net/lists/git/](http://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg67309.html)):

> The thing is, `--date-order` strings out and mixes up the commits on the 
>   same development chain, and by doing so it makes the different chains of 
>   development much harder to see.
>   It also ends up showing the development in 
>   a more "parallel" way, which in turn makes the view even harder to read.
>
> So I would suggest not using `--date-order` by default. It doesn't add 
>   anything to any normal flow, and it makes the big picture harder to see.
>
> The only time you really want `--date-order` (or "`-d`", which is shorthand 
>   for it for just `gitk`) is really
>
> - when the big picture is really really simple, and you actually want to 
>     see more detail because the big picture is too trivial to even be 
>     interesting otherwise.
>     (In other words: `--date-order` is fine for really simple development 
>     where there is only ever just a couple of branches or where you have 
>     pruned away so much of the history that the remaining part is simple)
> - when you want to debug "`git rev-list`" behaviour itself, since the date 
>     order actually matters for how git traverses the commit chains.
>
> The second case is something that I suspect nobody but me and a few other 
>   people have ever done.
>   I found it very useful together with `--show-all` when I was debugging the revision walker (see commits "[Add "`--show-all`" revision walker flag for debugging](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3131b713013f06285cad3ffdcc61f417ac4ba158)" and "[Make revision limiting more robust against occasional bad commit dates](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d004199d134c9d465e013064f72dbc04507f6c0) ",
>   where the first implements `--show-all`, and the second one is the end 
>   result of my debugging).
>
> In other words: never start out with "`-d`" or "`--date-order`" by default.
>   Only if you have some reason to then think that the view is too simple or 
>   you need to drill down into the commit relationships should you use it.

Comment: Note: if `-d` or `--date-order` is really the argument you are after, better not using too much, according to Linus himself: http://amailbox.org/mailarchive/git/2008/5/28/1958754

Comment: Your link is broken (now). Why shouldn't you use it too much?

Comment: @JonnyJD I have restored the link and include its content in the answer.