# How can I make git log order based on author's timestamp?

Tags: git, sorting, timestamp, git-log

I use a fairly complex `git-log` command involving `--date-order` to get an overview of my repository's status; but unfortunately, `--date-order` seems to use the *committer* date, not the *author* date. That means that each time I bring my topic branches up to date by rebasing them onto the current upstream, I lose the helpful chronological ordering in my `git-log` of relative commits in my topic branches (that is, each branch becomes a single long line, because all of its commits got rebased to sequential and nearly-identical committer timestamps.)

If I could get `git-log` to order commits by the *author* timestamp instead of the *committer* timestamp, this would be solved. Does anybody know of a way to do that?

---

For those visiting this from Google results, you may want to look into [josephdpurcell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/990642/josephdpurcell)'s solution (and [in-depth blog post](http://thesimplesynthesis.com/post/how-to-sort-git-commits-by-author-date/)!), below. It's quite excellent, if you're looking for standard `git-log` style output, multi-line, with detailed messages about each commit.

Unfortunate, I now need to amend this question, because I'm an idiot and didn't provide more specific information about my use-case: I use `git-log` in “`--graph` mode,” and I need to make **`git-log` itself** operate in author-date-order. As far as I've been able to ascertain, this is completely impossible to do from outside `git-log`, because `git-log` *itself* handles the graph ordering and printing.

A script, or patch for `git-log`, may be necessary, it seems. I'll leave this open until somebody can either 1. write such a script, or 2. we can talk the `git` authors into including a `--author --date-order` combination of flags. (=

---

For reference, here's what my current [`glog` function](https://github.com/elliottcable/System/blob/Master/Dotfiles/profile#L180-L189)'s output looks like, and what I need to re-order:

[image: glog output]

Answer (score 81, accepted):

git version 1.8.4 added an `--author-date-order` argument to `git log`; according to the [release notes](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt), "the output is topologically sorted and commits in parallel histories are shown intermixed together based on the author timestamp."

Comment: Heh. I actually did a lot of the work here (after posting this question), but didn't realize it'd ever gotten cleaned up and mainlined. Cool! Thanks for the heads-up. I'll test that it indeed solves my actual, original problem, and then probably accept this answer.

Comment: I had the same (or very similar) issue, and adding this to my log alias makes it far more readable now. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Okay, this took me a very long time to figure out ([details](http://thesimplesynthesis.com/post/how-to-sort-git-commits-by-author-date/)). In short, I found many examples that were either incomplete or incorrect. The following command does what I *think* you would expect:

```
$ git log --pretty="format:%at %C(yellow)commit %H%Creset\nAuthor: %an <%ae>\nDate: %aD\n\n %s\n" | sort -r | cut -d" " -f2- | sed -e "s/\\\n/\\`echo -e '\n\r'`/g" | tr -d '\15\32' | less -R
```

You can find this script and others in [Git Extras](https://github.com/josephdpurcell/git-extras) on GitHub.

Comment: +1 Yes! simple and sweet. And also +1 for the whole blog explanation.

Comment: And if you want to turn this into an alias: `alias prettylog=git log --pretty='format:%at %C(yellow)commit %H%Creset\nAuthor: %an <%ae>\nDate: %aD\n\n %s\n' | sort -r | cut -d' ' -f2- | sed -e 's/\\\n/\\`echo -e '\n\r'\`/g' | tr -d '\15\32' | less -R"`

Comment: I was actually looking to a precursor from your solution (I'm setting up a one-line log; so all the multi-line and `tr` nonesense was irrelevant to me) … but since you condensed all your research into a blog post (you sly devil!), I was able to use one of your previous incarnations. Best response I've ever gotten out of S.O.; wish I could upvote you twice. (=

Comment: I got super-excited about this solution, until I realized it doesn't support `--graph`, which completely defeats the purpose for me. Without `--graph`, I can't see the *structure* of my history, which makes `git-log` useless to me as a whole. >:

Answer (score 13):

`--date-order`/`--topo-order` really just controls the ordering of commits in a revision list when you are viewing multiple branches running alongside another. The "x is-a-parent of y" relationship is *always* respected, even if your committer/authoring timestamp is in the distant past or future.

You'd need something like `git log --pretty="format:%at %H" | sort -g` and then feed the hashes back into `git log`.

Answer (score 2):

Building off of what jørgensen suggested there is a "one-liner" solution that may give you what you are looking for.  Formatted here for easier viewing.  Improvements are welcomed!

```
SORTED_GIT_LOGS=$(git log --pretty="format:%at %H" | sort -g | cut -d' ' -f2); \
    IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b"); for LOG in $SORTED_GIT_LOGS; do \
        git show --name-only $LOG; \
    done | less
```