# Logging git commits till a commit id when pulled with git pull --rebase

Tags: git, git-log

Lets Suppose the git log has the following commits

```
commit15
commit14
commit13
commit12
commit11
commit10
.
.
.
commit1
```

I tried saving the git log till commit 14 to a file by

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h|%H|%an|%ai|%s' $commitid | grep -v "Merge branch 'master' of" > 'path to log file which should contain git log till that Commitid'
```

This is working fine except for one case,i.e.

When commit12 and commit13 were pushed after pulling with `git pull --rebase`,when i try to save the git log till commit14 using `git log commit14` i cant see the commits12 and commits13 but when i try to log till commit15 using `git log commit15` the commits 12 and 13 are listed under commit14

I understand the problem is with --rebase,Is there any way i can log the commits till a particular id even it has commits below it which have been rebased onto the top of it? (I saw the git repo, commit12 and commit13 are listed under commit14)

Comment: it seems like part of your question is missing: "when i try to... ??"

Comment: @ChrisMaes it was a mistake i pressed Ctrl+enter when editing question.i am done with editing Please look into the question

Comment: your question is still hard to understand. I guess the problem is you want your log to be ordered according to creation date and not their place in the tree?

Comment: eg 12 and 13 were created before 14; but due to rebase they appear AFTER 14.. is that your problem?

Comment: you can try the --author-date-order option: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18871907/2082964

Comment: @Yeah i tried --author-date-order its showing unrecognized argument,

Comment: it only exists since git 1.8.4.... can you update your git?