# Git Log default order criteria

Tags: git

When I run `git log --oneline` for example, it outputs a list of commits in chronologic order (descendent). My question is: What criteria git uses to sort this list? Does it use the `author_date` or the `committer_date` to order the result? Or it uses another? This can be an issue for me if it sort by `committer_date` as this attribute can *change* over time. I appreciate any help about this.

Comment: As an extra note : try adding `--graph` to your `git log` commands to have a better view of how commits are ordered -- for example : to view the difference between `--date-order` and `--topo-order`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the primary sort criterion is given by the parent-child relationships, which are **always** respected in log listings (if three commits are chained `A->B->C` they will never be displayed in `A C B` order, no matter the dates or the log options).

But when we are displaying commits from paralell branches, there is some freedom in the ordering.
For this scenario, there exist the options `--date-order --topo-order`. And here, "date-order" (the default) means the **`committer_date`**. If you wish to sort by the author date, there is the additional option `--author-date-order`.

If you are listing commits from a single branch, then these options are irrelevant.

Doc: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering

```
---1----2----4----7
    \              \
     3----5----6----8----9--
```

Suppose you have this commit history (copied from docs) where the horizontal coordinate corresponds to the (author) date. Then the log list will display:

```
date-order  topo-order      topo-order (alt)
   9             9              9  
   8             8              8  
   7             6              7  
   6             5              4  
   4             3              2  
   5             7              6  
   2             4              5  
   3             2              3  
   1             1              1
```

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576503)

Comment: topological is the default behavior? because in the docs it says "By default, the commits are shown in reverse chronological order."

Comment: @Maigret Perhaps it's more clear now? If not, see the linked docs

Comment: let me see if a got it: if I want to traverse only commits in **one** branch (let's say master branch), it will follow the parent-child relationship order. But if I want to traverse all commits considering **n** possible branches, it will default to date-order (commiter_date) as the order criterion? I'm not considering here using additional options, just want to know the default behavior of git log.

Comment: Not exactly. The commits in each (sub)branch are first ordered by parent-child. Then, paralell braches are intermixed by commiter_date order. See the figure in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering

Comment: This answer incorrect.  In order for log listings to respect the parent child relationships, `--topo-order` must be used.  Otherwise `git log master` would return exactly the same result as `git log master --topo-order`.  But, in reality, the results differ.