# Display gitk log in reverse order

Tags: git, gitk

**Is there any way to reverse the order of the visual commit log view that displays in [gitk](/questions/tagged/gitk)?**

I'm talking about visual representation that renders in **[gitk](/questions/tagged/gitk)** in color as a tree view; i.e., the GUI version of what you get when you run something like this in the terminal:

```bsh
git log --graph --online --abbrev-commit
```

I've looked in the menu under <kbd>Edit</kbd> <kbd>Preferences</kbd> and <kbd>View</kbd> <kbd>New view...</kbd>, but I couldn't find anything that pertained to the ordering of the commits.

I know I can display the commit log in reverse order in the terminal by adding the `--reverse` flag:

```bsh
git log --reverse --oneline --abbrev-commit
# Displays list correctly
```

But it doesn't seem to play nicely with the `--graph` flag:

```bsh
git log --reverse --oneline --abbrev-commit --graph
# fatal: cannot combine --reverse with --graph
```

Perhaps this is why [gitk](/questions/tagged/gitk) doesn't give us the option to render the view in reverse.

At any rate, I'd like to know: **is possible in [gitk](/questions/tagged/gitk) to reverse the order of the commit log view**?

Comment: I know this is not exactly what you wanted, but you can look into [`git-forest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15562953/380757), a script that will let you display the graph on the console, even when used with `--reverse` option. It parses the output from `git-log` and hence all options supported with `git-log` can be passed to this script as well.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question, but darn that is some fine markup +1

Answer (score 3):

`gitk` mostly accepts the same arguments as `git rev-list` ([git: Is there a command line option for "Sort by date" for gitk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187767/git-is-there-a-command-line-option-for-sort-by-date)). However the `--reverse` argument, which would show the commits in descending order, is [specifically excluded](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/gitk-git/gitk#n202):

```
"--objects" - "--objects-edge" - "--reverse"
    # These cause our parsing of git log's output to fail, or else
    # they're options we want to set ourselves, so ignore them.
```

(Added in [ee66e089c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/commit?id=ee66e089c1d4162765a3cec79fd5406e515b0db1).)

Commenting it out and running with `gitk --reverse` *seems* to work, but I'm not sure if that would be accepted upstream as a patch.