# Chronological list of branches?

Tags: git

Is there a way to have the list of your (local) branches ordered by the date of the last commit on it (along with the id of the commit, maybe)?
When you have tons of branches, like me, it could be sometime useful just to have a look at your most recent work just looking at the list of branches (without inspecting the logs).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5188320/608457 - but +1 as I didn't know this was possible. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as explained in [How can I get a list of git branches, ordered by most recent commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5188320/608457) but an easier way would be to install gitk which does exactly what your are doing. Gitk provides views than can display the all branches or only the branch that you want sorted by some field, like last commit, author, title, etc.

To learn it is really easy. Here is another related question to gitk [Guide to understanding gitk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570535/guide-to-understanding-gitk)