# Using git, why don't commits appear in the history after merging into a feature branch?

Tags: git

I have 2 branches, the main branch and a feature branch. Both branches had ongoing changes. I merged changes from the main branch into the feature branch. There were a few conflicts, which I resolved. I then staged the updated files.

In the merge, there were a number of other commits that **didn't** have any conflicting files.

With that, there are 2 things I don't understand.

1. For the commits that didn't have any conflicts, shouldn't they show up in the history of the feature branch? Following the merge, there is nothing in the feature branch history for any of the work that was done on the main branch.
2. Pertaining again to the commits that didn't have any conflicts, why do those files show up as being changed when running git status on the feature branch?

Admittedly, there is probably something fundamentally missing in my understanding of what should happen...

Comment: (1) Given the above text, did you actually do a commit?  (2) How are you viewing the history?  Note that a true merge creates a (single) new commit that has two parent commits: the first parent is the branch you were and are still on, and the second parent is what was merged-in.  A history viewer must necessarily follow both forks of history.  Many (e.g., `git log --graph` and `gitk`) draw lines with nodes to help you identify which commits are on which line-of-development.

Comment: @torek - You asked if I actually did a commit. Do you mean on the feature branch following everything else I did, or something else?

Comment: @torek - I've been viewing the history with git log --oneline. Perhaps that's my problem in understanding the history?

Comment: (1) A merge with no conflicts will do a commit for you, but a merge with conflicts stops, has you fix them yourself, `git add` the results, and `git commit` to conclude the merge.  Your description says you did the `add` step but not the `commit`...  (2) with `git log --oneline`, try adding `--graph` (and I like `--decorate` as well).

Comment: @torek - Thanks. I completely understand I have to commit again, but why do I have to commit the files that had no conflicts to begin with? Shouldn't I just be committing the fixed conflicting files?

Comment: Ah - there's one of your issues: a commit doesn't commit particular files, but rather an entire *tree*.  Specifically it commits the tree produced by the current "index" (staging-area).  A `git add` command updates the index, but the index starts with the contents of the *previous* commit.  Meanwhile the part of the merge that succeeds on its own, adds any changed files to the index, leaving only the conflicted parts (which are also in the index, really) for you to resolve.  Then you commit the final index as the new merge commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For the commits that didn't have any conflicts, shouldn't they show up in the history of the feature branch? Following the merge, there is nothing in the feature branch history for any of the work that was done on the main branch.

In your question, you talk about merge conflicts happening on *commits*.

> In the merge, there were a number of other commits that didn't have any conflicting files.

Git doesn't merge commits, it merges content.  This indicates to me you have a misconception about how Git works (which Git doesn't do much to dispel, so no worries).  Let's sketch what your repository looks like before a merge...

```
A - B - C - D - E - F [master]
         \
          1 - 2 - 3 [feature]
```

You have a master branch with commits A, B, C ... F.  Then you have a feature branch off of C with commits 1, 2 and 3.  You can see this with `git log --graph --decorate --all` or you can use a graphical tool such as [gitk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570535/guide-to-understanding-gitk) or [GitX-dev](https://rowanj.github.io/gitx/)

You want to merge the changes from master into feature.  Git merges by taking the content of master and feature and *creating a new commit* which combines the two.

```
A - B - C - D - E - F [master]
         \           \
          1 - 2 - 3 - F3 [feature]
```

[How it does that merge is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366860/when-would-you-use-the-different-git-merge-strategies).  The important thing to realize is Git is merging the *content* of F and the *content* of 3.

You can see from the graph, feature and master aren't woven together.  feature's history remains distinct from master's history.  *Branches do not go away when you merge*.  If you continue to commit to feature and master, they will diverge again.

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H [master]
         \           \
          1 - 2 - 3 - F3 - 4 - 5 [feature]
```

This is why it may not appear that master's history is showing up in feature's, but it is now that F3 has both F and 3 as its parents.

> Pertaining again to the commits that didn't have any conflicts, why do those files show up as being changed when running git status on the feature branch?

As mentioned above, when Git does a merge it's creating a new commit with the combined changes in the two branches.  This is a normal commit like any other except it has more than one parent.  If there is a conflict, Git needs a human to resolve it.  You're left with Git's unfinished work.  Any files which Git was able to merge successfully will be changed and staged (added).  Anything which had a conflict will be changed (with conflict markers) and left unstaged.  It's up to you to edit the conflicted files, add them and commit.  Same process as normal.

Comment: Thank you much for your detailed explanation, it helped in many ways. Pertaining to my last question, my concern was when I eventually merge the feature branch into the main branch it would appear in the history that I changed those files, which I didn't. I'm still wondering, how would another onlooker know to look back further in the history for details (comments) on why/how those files were changed?

Comment: @scoots Git history is non-linear. There are tools for archeology in Git: the visualization tools to view the history as it is, not the seemingly linear representation `git log` shows; `git blame` to show who changed what line and when; you can diff between branches. To avoid this problem altogether, and if you haven't pushed your branch, you can rebase instead of merge; it will rewrite your changes at the end of master as if you had been working on the latest version all along. You can get in trouble with this technique, you need good understanding of how Git works.

Answer (score 3):

I think the fundamental notion about Git that's missing is this:

> In Git each commit represents *a snapshot of your entire directory tree* at a certain point in time.

When you issue commands like `git show <commitref>`, Git is comparing the *current* state of your working tree with the state your working tree was at the point in time *when that commit was made* and showing you the net differences.

Now, when you merge two branches, say `A` and `B`, you're actually merging the snapshots of your directory tree as they were at the time *when the latest commits were made* in branch A and branch B, in this example `C3` and `C5`.

```
C1 - C2 - C3 <-- A
      \       
       C4 - C5 <-- B
```

The resulting merge commit represents the *sum* of the two snapshots of your directory tree referenced by `C3` and `C5`. In other words, the snapshot in `C5` is put on top of `C3`, producing a new snapshot called `C5'`, or "*C5 prime*". That merge snapshot is special in that *it has two parents* instead of just one.

```
C1 - C2 - C3 - C5' <-- A
      \       /
       C4 - C5 <-- B
```

If both snapshots contain different versions of the *same lines* in the *same files* a conflict emerges. In that case, you have to decide how those lines are going to look like in the merged snapshot.

Remember, since each commit is a snapshot representing the *cumulative transformations* that your directory tree has gone through before it, a merge commit is just a new snapshot, not a sequence of snapshots.

That's why you don't see a list of commits from your main branch into your feature branch. Instead, you get a merge commit that represents *the sum of the transformations* that have happened to your files in the two branches. In order to allow you to track backwards through those earlier transformations, a merge commit contains a reference to the latest commits that were summed together.

Comment: It is a bit strange to call the merge commit C5'. This notation usually indicates a commit that is a copy of another, such as with cherry picking and rebase. However, as this answer correctly explains, the merge commit is an entirely new snapshot of history combining the work of both branch, and it should therefore probably be C6.

Comment: @JosephK.Strauss In Git, the _prime_ notation is used in the same way as in math, i.e. to indicate the [complement of a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)). In this example, merging branch `B` into `A` means taking the snapshot referenced by `B` (`C5`) and applying it on top of the snapshot referenced by `A` (`C3`). The resulting commit contains the changes from `C3` that aren't in `C5`, in other words the _complement set_ of `C5` or `C5'`.